# make ajax calls multiples times to update end user's results

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to use AJAX and PHP to update the browser results multiple times.

The code here will call a getDest.php file to retrieve all the html files that will be appended to a div id called `results`, and there are about 21 cities. I want to show each city one by one instead of showing all of them at once.

I have tried many different methods, any help is appreciated.

```
<script>
function hideContainer() {
  jQuery('.city_container').hide();
};
function showContainer() {
  jQuery('.citywrapper').hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.city_container').show();
  },
  function() {
    jQuery('.city_container').hide();
  });
};
</script>

<script>
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "getDest.php"
}).done(function( html ) {
  $("#results").append(html);
  hideContainer();
  showContainer();
});
</script>
```

getDest.php

```
<div class="citywrapper">city1 <div class="city_container">descript1</div></div>
<div class="citywrapper">city2 <div class="city_container">descript2</div></div>
<div class="citywrapper">city3 <div class="city_container">descript3</div></div>
<div class="citywrapper">city4 <div class="city_container">descript4</div></div>
<div class="citywrapper">city5 <div class="city_container">descript5</div></div>
<div class="citywrapper">city6 <div class="city_container">descript6</div></div>
....
```

Comment: To understand you quenstion: you load your whole content and want to show first descript1, after another specific time (second, minute, ...) descript2, after another second descript3, ... and so on?

Comment: yes, you are right da_re

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this? If your ajax call is returning all the HTML at once, I can't imagine why you would want to make the call multiple times.

I added in comments to explain exactly what is happening here, in case you are not too familiar with jQuery.

```
<script>
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "getDest.php",
    success: function(html) {

      // Wrap the raw html into a jquery object
      var elements = $(html);

      // Loop through each top-level element in jquery object.
      $.each(elements, function(i, el) {

        setTimeout(function() {

          // el points to the element at position i in jquery object 'elements'
          $('#results').append(el);

        // Each element takes one more second to append than the previous one
        }, i * 1000);
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Instead of just append, you can always do a neat animation by appending the element with a 'display: none' CSS property, and then showing it with a jQuery animation such as "el.slideDown()" or "el.fadeIn()".

If you want it to be more than one second in between results being appended, simply exchange

```
i * 1000
```

for

```
i * seconds_in_between * 1000
```

You should take into account whether it matters to you for the previous element to finish displaying before the next one does -- as that will affect the time needed.

Also, for the sake of best practice, include an 'error' function alongside that 'success' function, just in case the request fails. You don't want the user clicking a ton of times only to find that nothing is happening -- be sure to let them know what failed. E.g. "Could not load city list."

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Monica for the prompt response, but this script seems to show all the cities at once without the setTimeout function, but with the setTimeout function, it will only show the last element in the array elements...any ideas?i really like this method.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, didn't see this before. Did you have that problem when you put the setTimeout inside the for loop? I tried this at the REPL and it seemed to work properly for me. I'll look into it further if you're still hoping to implement this solution :) -- I think the problem is that 'i' has gotten to the end of the loop before the timeout callback occurs, and by then 'i' is the last element. I think you could do this recursively by putting each subsequent timeout in the success function of the previous timeout.

Comment: I think you are right, i am still wishing to implement this method. It seems quite interesting. Can you please show me more codes? How do you recursively call the timeout function in the success function? I would love to learn your method. Thanks very much.

Comment: See my edited answer. It ended up being simpler than doing it recursively -- in the revision, 'el' maintains its reference to the correct element, whereas in the previous for loop, it did not. This worked perfectly for me in the console doing logs instead of appends -- let me know how it goes for you!

Comment: I already mentioned that in my answer -- set each element's css style to 'display: none', append the element, then call $(el).fadeIn().

Comment: that is awesome. I learnt a lot from your code. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1):

I created a [code snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/gnMTX/) on JSFiddle for you. Here the main part:

```
$(".city_container").each(function(index) {
    var cityContainer = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(cityContainer).slideDown();
    }, index * 2000 );
});
```

After you've added the content to the DOM you can iterate with [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) over every item. Then set a timeout for every item (**in ms**). After the timeout the item will be displayed. You can also use `show()` or anything else instead of `slideDown()` do display the content :) .

Comment: This is great, can i please have a slideright() effect? I'm quite new to JQuery..thanks for the great demo.

Comment: jQuery has no `slideRight` method. But you can use the [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method to accomplish this :) . I've updated the [JSFiddle (click me)](http://jsfiddle.net/gnMTX/1/).

Comment: If you don't want the empty space you can add the CSS attribute `height` -> [another JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jJbbT/).